# Python doesn't find a directory using the home sign ~

Tags: python, linux, macos

I have created a small Python script to save directories in a side directory, under the current user.
I am running on Mac but production is Ubuntu

My problem is the **it doesn't manage to identify the dir with the home sign `~`**

```
>>> os.path.exists('/Users/partuck/cache_dir/bla')
True
>>> os.path.exists('~/cache_dir/bla')
False
>>> os.system('echo "$USER"')
partuck
0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the docs (here, from the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob)):

> (For tilde and shell variable expansion, use [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars).)

You want `os.path.expanduser()`.

Comment: ```os.environ["HOME"] = "/home/cgi/"
os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
``` 
worked for me (replace user name)

Answer (score 0):

```
os.environ["HOME"] = "/Users/partuck/
os.path.expanduser("~/cache_dir/bla")
```

(@jedwards answer pointed out `expanduser`)