# Paramiko can not access private key

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, file-permissions, paramiko

After a distribution upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04. to 20.04.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/deploy/old_ssh.py", line 50, in async_ssh
    ssh.connect(
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 435, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 676, in _auth
    key = self._key_from_filepath(
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 586, in _key_from_filepath
    key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 235, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/home/cgi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 307, in _read_private_key_file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
```

But it is there:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<no one is so stupid>
```

Permissions:

```
sudo$ ll /home/cgi/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw------- 1 cgi cgi 6363 Jul 29  2019 /home/cgi/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The script is run under user `cgi` as part of a `supervisord`. Any help why `paramiko` can not read it?

** Update **

It looks like that I also can not open it from python3 shell directly
[image: can-not-open-ssh-private-key-from-python]

But it can be done, using the **absolute path**:

[image: can-open-ssh-private-key-from-python-absolute-path]

**So it looks like the `~` is not interpreted as my user (`cgi`) within the python environment.**

```
> os.path.expanduser("~")
< '/home/cgi'
```

but I can not `chdir` or `listdir` it:

```
> os.listdir('~')
< FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~'
```

Comment: Can you do `open("~/.ssh/id_rsa", "r")`? + What does `os.path.expanduser("~")` return?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for your response. I did some testing around it and updated the question.

Comment: So what do you get in shell, if you do `cd ~`, `pwd`? + What about Python `os.path.expanduser("~")`?

Comment: `>>> os.path.expanduser("~")` --> `/home/cgi`. `os.listdir('~')` --> `No such file or directory: '~'`

Comment: See [Python doesn't find a directory using the home sign ~](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29339944/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl you have been right. Posted an answer below to close it - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinPrikryl correctly pointed out, the `~` is not found. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29339944/850848)

Execute these commands before initalizing the `paramiko` connection:

```
os.environ["HOME"] = "/home/cgi/"
os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
```