# Paramiko, private keys and cron

Tags: python-3.x, cron, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am having some issues while trying to setup a paramiko scp using private public keys.

The problem is not so much related to the paramiko itself, I think, but the fact this is launched in a Cron (user cron (crontab -e)).

So the script works from the normal terminal, but it does not from the cron. I tried to specify the exact location of the private key (key_filename="/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa") when calling the method connect. It returns back the following error: "Not a valid RSA private key file".

On the other hand, in the cron, I tried to declare the terminal to use:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=... (all the typical values)
HOME=/home/myuser
```

Also tried to source the $HOME/profile prior to launching the task.

It keeps failing.

Either making the cron execution environment to have all the variables as a normal bash or being able to properly specify to paramiko the location of the private key would make it, but all the things I tried did not work.

I also tried: [Paramiko can not access private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031455/paramiko-can-not-access-private-key)
But it did not work.

And this problem [Paramiko: "not a valid RSA private key file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612609/paramiko-not-a-valid-rsa-private-key-file) is not applicable, because the script works when launched from a normal terminal with that user. It fails with the cron.

Any clue?

Python3
Paramiko 2.6.0
Ubuntu 20.4.2 LTS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Prikryl, after activating the paramiko logging, which reported an error about something not implemented I ended here:

[Getting Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented') while connecting SFTP with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691213/getting-oops-unhandled-type-3-unimplemented-while-connecting-sftp-with-para)

By applying the private key as per that post (and making a conversion as per this other post: [Paramiko: "not a valid RSA private key file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612609/paramiko-not-a-valid-rsa-private-key-file) Note I am using the Paramiko 2.6.0)...

Now it works!!

Thanks, Martin!

Comment: It is a problem with the path, so you can sort it out by indicating where the private key is. For that, and for the paramiko version I specified above, you need to use the key in the format defined in the other link.

Comment: This answer does not explain why does it work in cron.

Comment: it is a problem with path, accessible to cron.

See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths

As I was saying before, you can indicate where they private key is to paramiko with absolute path, and modify the format as per the link above because of the version. With that it works, and because of the reason above it works with cron

Comment: So say that in your answer.